# Delete previously added viewControllers from the UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using an array to add some viewControllers on the UIPageViewController. The problem is that they stay in memory when you swipe further and I want to delete them. I found this delegate method:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    // If the page did not turn
    if (!completed)
    {
        return;
    }
    // This is where I want to delete the previousViewControllers to release memory
}
```

But how do I delete those previousViewControllers? If you scroll back they need to reload but I need to remove them because otherwise they stay in memory the whole time.

Comment: The UIPageViewController should hang onto a maximum of 3 controllers (current, previous, next) and you should never (and in fact can't really) delete the ones it is holding onto.  If your controllers are hanging around longer than that, perhaps it is because you are keeping a reference to them in that array you add them from.  After you give them to UIPageViewController you should be able to safely set any pointer that you have to the viewController to nil because UIPageViewController keeps a strong pointer to them.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used `UIPageViewController`, but it seems that `previousViewControllers` is a read-only. What I would do is send a message to the previous ViewControllers, telling them to reload.

For example, I believe this will access the last ViewController displayed :

```
MyVC *lastVC = (MyVC*)[previousViewControllers objectAtIndex:[previousViewControllers count]-1];
lastVC.reloadFlag = YES; // Assuming you have a reloadFlag property in your MyVC class
```

So you can put that in the method you have in your question.

Then make sure `viewWillAppear` is called in your `MyVC *` object when you go back to your ViewController, and if it is, put a simple thing in it:

```
if(_reloadFlag) {
    //updateUI
}
```

This is just an idea, you may have to change some stuff to make it work.

Comment: The problem is that the viewControllers that are added on the UIPageViewController are from different classes, so for example not only "MyVC" but also MyVC2, MyVC3, MyVC4, etc...

Comment: Maybe you can have all your VC classes inherit from a superclass which would have the flag as a property ?

Comment: Or you add the flag to all your classes (if there isn't too many) and check the class with *[lastVC isKindOfClass:@"..."]* ?